# How to call same URL with different URL in CI with route

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I want to call my URL with different name and in that calling the same controller with the same method.

http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/HelloWorld_2

Actual path of this will be something like this

http://localhost/CodeIgniter/ControllerName/FunctionName

I tried but it doesn't works. Can anyone help me?

```
$route['HelloWorld'] = 'ControllerName/FunctionName';
$route['HelloWorld_2'] = 'ControllerName/FunctionName';
```

Comment: In `config.php` set `$config['base_url'] = '/CodeIgniter/';` and `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: `how to call` mean from where you want to call from the `url` or from the `link`

Comment: @Girish Make sure you load URL helper. because code looks correct.